# possible to execute .exe and get console outputs in html?

Tags: php, execute

Is it possible to call a .exe (console application) and get the console output realtime on my webpage?

I know the command `shell_exec()` function for PHP. With this, I can execute my .exe. But it would be great if the output of the console would be displayed as HTML Code. With this way, the user would always know the exact state of the application.

If this is possible, could you give me any keywords how I can search for it?

Edit:
I am going to upload a videofile.

HTML:

```
        <form action="upload_file.php" method="post"
        enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="file" id="file"><br>
        <input type="submit" name="uploadbtn" value="Upload Video">
```

this file goes to a php script for validation:

PHP Script:

```
if (in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
  {
  echo "<p>";
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
  else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";

    if (file_exists("../Videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
    else
      {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "../Videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "Videos/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];

      $output = shell_exec("Extractvideo.exe $_FILES["file"]["name"]");
      echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
      }
     ?>
      <p>File erfolgreich hochgeladen!</p>
      <br/>
      <a href="watch.php">Hier gehts zur Videoliste</a>
      <?php
    }
  echo "</p>";
  }
else
  {
  echo "Invalid file";
  }            
?>
```

I get the following output:

> Upload: ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv Type: video/x-ms-wmv Size: 12964.57421875
>   kB Stored in: Videos/ELL_PART_5_768k.wmv
>
> File erfolgreich hochgeladen!

My "Videoextract.exe" does convert the video. 
While it is converting it gives informations about it's actual state.

Example Console Application:

```
Video is going to be rendered
20%
40%
60%
80%
100%
Success!
```

It would be nice if the user could get the outputs of the console application *in realtime*!

Because my console application has a built in errorhandler. So I could return any error in the console application instead of rewriting it in PHP.

Also, it would be nice if the user could see the whole process, so he know when it has finished.

If I use

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('Extractvideo.exe');
echo "<pre>$output</pre>";
?>
```

The script would wait UNTIL its finished and then return the final string. But thats not real time for me!

Comment: Just take the output and format it as HTML.  What's the issue?  See the example in the docs: http://php.net/shell_exec

Comment: You can use http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php The documentation even has a sample on how to do it.

Comment: What is the format of your output?  What does it look like?

Comment: I have the impression that if you were trying to do advanced stuff like capturing ANSI escape codes, full-screen output or graphical output... you would have mentioned it explicitly. Please make yourself familiar with the basic usage of shell execution functions and feel free to post again when you have precise questions with your code.

Comment: Updated with code examples! :)